# Copy/Paste Functionality Problem in Windows XP & Firefox

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, copy-paste

I am using Windows XP. When I use Firefox browser, select all and copy and then paste it into some application such as OneNote, it only pastes the text (preserves text formatting) but not the images. I have another PC in which it copies both images and text. Both have same version of FF and mostly everything is the same. I think there is some problem with clipboard. Can you suggest what could be the cause?

Comment: I can copy text and images in IE7 on same comp.

Answer (score 1):

This is what solved the problem for me.
Set signed.applets.codebase_principal_support to true via about:config. This is not recommended as you cannot limit which sites have these extra privileges.

Refer
http://kb.mozillazine.org/Granting_JavaScript_access_to_the_clipboard for specifics and how to do it in more secure fashion.

Answer (score 0):

most likely you are using normal text editor (Notepad, Wordpad etc.) where you paste from clipboard, better use rich text editor like MS-Word (From MS-office suite).

I think it will solve your problem !!

Comment: Actually I am using MS Onenote 2007 (part of Office suite). I can paste rich text including images from IE 7 into it but pasting from firefox only pastes the text.

Comment: Try using firefox's any add-on like (AllowClipboard Helper,Clipboard Observer,Clipboard-Save-as and Dafizilla Table2Clipboard),it might solve your problem

Comment: Ok thanks. AllowClipboard helper seems to work but we have to add each server to it manually. So i took a look at it s documentation and it says that access to clipboard by scripts is disabled by default in firefox. So i enabled by setting signed.applets.codebase_principal_support to true in about:config. It is not recommended though, because of security issues.